# Select td's that contains numeric values from a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectors

I have a table with some dynamically generated data. The issue is I want to select all `<td>'s` that has numeric (formatted or non-formatted) data type and apply some style to them. How best can I do this with jQuery or JavaScript?
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Days</th>
    <th>Booth 1</th>
    <th>Booth 2</th>
    <th>Booth 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>2,500</td>
    <td>0</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>4,200</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>3,500</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Out Of Order</td>
    <td>Busy</td>
    <td>11,540</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about something like

```
$('td').each(function () {
    if ($(this).html().match(/^\s*\d[\d,\.]*\s*$/)) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        // TODO: something cool
    }
});
```

Which uses a simple regex to match a digit then zero or more digits or commas or decimal points inside `<td>` elements. Then you can perform whatever action you like on the element.

Comment: This is completely amazing. Exactly what I want. Thanks a lot @rfausak

Answer (score 4):

You'd be better off to just add a class to those `td`s when they are generated server side.

If that's not an option, you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) with a regex:

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    return /^[.,\d]+$/.test( $.text(this) );
})
.css('color', 'blue'); // or anything else...
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m7gQL/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is the one in the message text and not in the heading, the best shot is probably to assign a suitable class attribute to cells containing numeric data. This is best done when generating the tabular data, since there you should know which kind of data you're generating. If this is not possible, you may need to write a loop that processes the cells and tries to parse their content (entire contain) according to a pattern for numbers. You would need to specify the kind of numeric data that might appear (e.g., just integers, or something else? and which notations?).

Comment: The `html table` generated at the server side is unpredictable when it comes to the number of columns and rows. It is generated from a complex `sql query` for report which varies from department to department so based on the result set the server side code counts the number of affected `sql tables` and generates columns for `html table`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by looking at the generated HTML, because even if a cell contains a number, the column's data type might still be, say, String. Instead, you must output this information when generating the HTML. So, the cells with numeric data types would get an attribute

```
<td class="numeric"> ... </td>
```

And `numeric` would be defined as

```
td.numeric { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('table td').each(function(){
    if (!isNaN($(this).html().replace(',','')))
    {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  })
});
```